# Running multiple stored procedures and exit when there is error

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a stored procedure which runs a series of stored procedure. Each procedure will insert into a table which has the column status and Err_msg. So if I run the 1st procedure and the status shows 'Failed' with the error message, I want to exit the procedure completely. How do I do that?
[image: Stored procedure to run multiple procedures]

[image: Status and err_msg columns]

Comment: Thank you for helping me solve the problem!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To exit from a procedure in PL/SQL we use a simple `RETURN` statement.

If I have assumed correctly, field3 is an  `OUT` parameter of each of your procedure called inside your main procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sequence_test 
AS
field3 VARCHAR2(200) := 'Success';
BEGIN

MARS_TRUNCATE_TABLES('test','test',field3);
IF field3 like 'Failed%'  THEN -- use  = 'Failed' if it has only that.
  RETURN;  --exit the procedure completely.
END IF;

MARS_INSERT_TABLE('test','test',field3);
IF field3 like 'Failed%'  THEN 
  RETURN;  
END IF;

-- ...
-- ... Similar statements for other procedure calls.

END;
/
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use "**Begin Tran**".

[Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/begin-transaction-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Why would the Microsoft SQL Server manual be helpful for an Oracle problem?

Comment: Even if this was relevant, it could still do with some more explanation.